# Duplicate [parshat-acharei-mot] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have duplicate tags of [parshat-acharei-mot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-acharei-mot) and [achrei-mos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achrei-mos).

Should these be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now merged these tags .